# What does fast/normal/slow mean for Pentax auto-iso?

Tags: iso, pentax, auto-iso

I'm very confused about the Pentax auto-iso implementation.  What does "fast/normal/slow" mean for the Auto-iso in the menu settings?  The camera in question is a K-3, but I think it applies pretty equally to Pentax's with this option.

Answer (score 2):

Those settings apply to the way Auto ISO works in Program or Tv/Av modes. When set to "Slow", it tries to keep the ISO setting as low as possible (withing the range) until it really has no choice but to boost ISO. It will change something else instead (either the shutter speed or aperture or both). "Fast" works the opposite way; it will prefer to boost ISO before making any radical adjustments to shutter speed or aperture. (Exactly what the preferences are, I'm not sure. There's usually a bias in program modes towards higher shutter speeds, slightly above the rule of thumb for handheld imaging for recognised lenses, but if there's a bias for apertures other than the max/min for Pentax, I don't know.) "Normal" treats shutter speed, aperture and ISO as essentially equal partners in the exposure triangle (with ISO being slightly less equal, at least the way I understand it, changing at a lower rate throughout the program range). The setting *shouldn't* make any difference when you're in TAv (or "automatic manual mode"), since the ISO is the only thing the camera can change automatically.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for something more specific.  When you say "Exactly what the preferences are, I'm not sure." - that's what I'm wondering.

Comment: @rfusca - It would take, at most, a half-dozen shots to see what it's doing with the aperture, and a person with a K3 in their hands is in a much better position to do that than I am. Go to Tv and see what happens as the aperture *should* be opening up beyond f/4 without "fast" selected.

Comment: Hmm I guess so.  It's just very non-obvious.  It obviously depends on focal length, but there's some kind of limits.   For example, at 70mm, slow/normal/fast is 50/100/200 shutter speed.  Its that at 50mm as well.  At 25, its like down to 25/50/100.  At 18 its also like 25/50/100.

Comment: Ok, its more complicated than that even.  At 70mm f/2.4 its 50/100/200 at 2.8 its 60/120/250.  Its just confusing.

Comment: For your testing, keep 2 things in mind: 1. Set the Program line to Normal if you're P mode. 2. I do not believe the aperture affects the behavior directly. Instead, it decides on whether to raise ISO or instead lower exposure time or open the aperture when it has still room to work with the ISO value. So you need to adjust the lighting every time you switch a setting, then see at which point it rather changes ISO over the other parameters.

Comment: From my own testing, I get the impression that the rule is simply: "Slow" and "Fast" curves raises the ISO setting one LV step later or earlier compared to the "Normal" curve. Could be wrong, though, as I only tested with P mode so far. Feel free to prove my theory wrong :)

Comment: A related question would be: How does this setting compare to the Program Line setting? I suppose that while we do have the "Program Line" setting to control how the P mode selects whether to keep the aperture open or closed as much as possible or keep the exposure time as short as possible, the ISO curve does a similar thing for the other modes (Av, Tv).

Comment: And another thing: One would expect that activating Shake Reduction would have some effect on the minimum exposure time, but it doesn't. That's one thing that could need improvement. If only Pentax, uh, Ricoh, were more approachable...

Comment: Thomas' comments about the program line setting are important. There is a complex interaction with the auto ISO speed setting. The program line option is how you tell it to bias towards certain aperture choices.

Comment: BTW, I've just documented a few related issues I've found with the K-3 on my crappy website: http://www.tempel.org/Photo/Photo#toc5

Comment: I"m got to dissect all that, but I'm glad that SR doesn't effect exposure time like you're suggesting.  You're assuming a static subject it seems.

Comment: @rfusca, yes, I assume a static object, like taking landscape shots when nearly dark. I'd like having an option to allow longer exposure times when SR is on - Pentax has a lot of similar customization options, and that's what I love Pentax for.